# Hashiwokakero Puzzle

Tags: grid-deduction

Rules:

1. Connect islands (the circles with numbers) with as many bridges as the number in the island.
2. Bridges can go only in a straight line horizontally or vertically.
3. There can be no more than two bridges between two islands.
4. Bridges cannot go across islands or other bridges.
5. The bridges will form a continuous link between all the islands.

[image: The puzzle that you need to solve]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge? By the way, I couldn't help but notice that this looks like a screenshot or photocopy of another source. Attribution is required on Puzzling, so could you please tell us the source?

Comment: "Bridges cannot go across islands or other bridges." I assume we can only use straight bridges, and not completely go around an island? :P

Comment: I think I've seen this type of puzzle in a crossword and variety puzzle magazine.

Comment: Does "continuous link" mean that you can get from any island to any island, or does it mean something else?

Comment: This is one of Nikoli's standard Hashiwokakero sizes (32 x 18) and perfectly matches the graphics found on Nikoli.com, where puzzles of this size would be behind a paywall.  It does not match any puzzles Nikoli has posted on this site for the past 180 days, but I am still quite certain the puzzle was screenshot from there.

Answer (score 7):

Took me quite a while to figure out, very intricate, thanks for sharing! Final few steps required less logic and more trial and error, though.

> [image: Solution]

Comment: Perhaps any downvoters could explains their vote? This solution seems perfectly valid to me. Btw, how did you create the picture? It's much more beautiful than my paint work-in-progress :P

Comment: Is this the only possible solution?

Comment: @Lolgast I made it in Paint.NET. I could have made it in Photoshop or programmed something, but didn't feel like putting too much effort into that, since the focus was on the puzzle-solving.

Comment: @Tweakimp I'm fairly confident this is the only possible solution. The logic I followed for most of the time was trying to find the pattern for each island or set of islands that would be valid. Whenever there were multiple possible configurations, I moved on to something else until I found one that only had one possible configuration. Rinse and repeat until the very end